# ufw Firewall disabled after reboot

Tags: ufw, debian-buster

On Debian Buster I have installed the UFW Firewall

However, after enabling

```
$ ufw enable
Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)? y
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
```

The Firewall is disabled after Reboot

```
$ ufw status
Status: inactive
```

The  Config-File looks like this:

```
nano /etc/ufw/ufw.conf
ENABLED=yes
```

Help is very appreachiated!

Comment: can we see `systemctl status ufw.service` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the service with a service manager.

```
sudo systemctl start ufw    # starts the service 
sudo systemctl enable ufw   # starts the service on boot
```

Answer (score 0):

`ufw enable` should do the same. See the first Output:

```
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
```

However, your suggestion:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable ufw
Synchronizing state of ufw.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd- 
sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable ufw
```

Has no effect:

```
$ ufw status
Status: inactive
```